# Visual Studio Code 2019 terminal not opening

Tags: visual-studio-code

I was using visual studio code 2019  for C++ Programs, and suddenly now I have seen that when I press `Ctrl + ~`  my VS code terminal is not opening.
It gets open and close again. **It is not showing any error.**

I tried uninstall and install again of VS code and I tried changing `setting.json` modification. I am not sure what it is going wrong.

*Please Note: after all this I tried using code runner but it was not helping, so
I again uninstalled it.*

My `setting.json` is like below

```
{
    "terminal.integrated.inheritEnv":true,
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": false,
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",
    "C_Cpp.default.compilerPath": "",
    "terminal.integrated.automationShell.windows": ""
}
```

Comment: Are you really using one of the first releases of this program? It has improved a lot, even in terms of performance, and I'm sure most current extensions will not even work.

Answer (score 0):

I have not a good fix but probably it can work.

Follow this step by step and hope it fixes it for you.

#### Step 1: Uninstall VS Code using Program and Features.

1. Press Windows Key + R
2. Enter `appwiz.cpl`
3. Press enter.

The Uninstall a Program window will be open. Find VS Code and uninstall it from there.

Close the window.

#### Step 2: Remove the saved data from the `Local` folder.

1. Press Windows Key + R
2. Enter `appdata`
3. Press enter.

The `AppData` folder of your current use will open. Now do:

4. Double Click and Open `Local` folder.
5. Find the folder named `Programs` and Open it.
6. If you see the folder named: `Microsoft VS Code` then delete it. (Only do it after you delete VS Code from `Uninstall a Program`) else, return to the Local folder.
7. Close the folder.

#### Step 3: Remove the saved data from `Roaming` folder.

1. Press Windows Key + R
2. Enter `Appdata`
3. Press Enter

The `Appdata` folder will open again.

4. Double Click and Open `Roaming` folder.
5. Find the folder named: `Code` and delete it. (Only if you have deleted VS Code from Uninstall a Program)

---

Now install the setup of VS Code and install it again. This issue, most probably solved. This is because the left over setting of VS Code can be stored in your PC in order to use again if install. So casual reinstallation can't help. If you remove the saved folder the previous settings will not be inherited as they will not exist. A new folder will be created and thus new setting will be used which can be set accordingly again.

Hope this helps to solve your problem. :)

Thank You! :D

Comment: Thanks for detail answer , but   even after doing this 
when i press ctrl +`  , my terminal open and close immediate

Comment: Did your VS Code looked any different after you did all of that and reinstalled it?

Comment: You had made any theme modifications or something?

Comment: I just followed all steps ...no any other modification

Comment: Did you have a Theme on your IDE?

Comment: everything default settings only

Comment: Ohk! I can't really find the issue now.

Comment: I was able to solve this with installing again Powershell.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this with installing again Powershell.

Comment: So you reinstalled powershell?